What is the alternative of "use to have to"
what is the used to form of have to as in the following example:

Turkmens used to have to read Ruhnama in order to get a driver's license. But now they needn't read the Ruhnama.


What Turkmens used to do means what they habitually did in the past. But in the cited context it doesn't really mean anything different to [In the past,] Turkmens had to read Ruhnama to get a driver's license. But I don't think your text came from a modern competent Anglophone, since almost everyone today would contrast that with But now they don't need to / don't have to read the Ruhnama (if they even considered such a lengthy negation of the preceding sentence). It looks like a non-idiomatic "teaching example" from a non-Anglophone.

See the example We used to have to go get tested every week. from sadly-no-longer-with-us Prof John Lawler on ELU. As he points out, we can't really call all those "stacked up" auxiliary verbs "tenses". As with the example here, John's doesn't really mean anything different to We had to be tested every week. But it's perfectly valid, and not uncommon or unusual to native speakers.

you have an error in the title ... it should be used to have to

@jsotola: Somewhere in all his posts about this usage, Prof Lawler pointed out that "nobody knows" whether it has to be use to or used to, because language is essentially spoken, and it's impossible to distinguish the two forms in speech. But see this usage chart showing that Where did you use / used to go on holiday? gets written both ways about equally often.

@FumbleFingers - I definitely say 'used to' differently from 'use to' if I think about it. It was the sort of thing our 1950s & 60s teachers (and my mother!) picked up on, along with dropped aitches, final Gs, saying 'ain't', etc. I regard wqriting 'use to' as I do such abominations as 'would of'.

@MichaelHarvey: I previously commented it's impossible for most Anglophones to enunciate (or hear) any difference between prints and prince (and I got that from Steven Pinker, who is a linguist). I can't even remember which of nearly a dozen of his books I got that from, and I can't find it online, and I don't recall whether and to what extent Pinker allowed that some people might be able to differentiate. Just that he said nearly everyone thinks they can, but they can't.

(He did tests with people saying what they heard, as well as studying oscilloscope output, I think.)

...not to belabour the point, but The Pilgrim's Progress has "Where did he use to commit his wickedness?", and Google Books finds no instances of over-zealous proofreaders changing that to used. Besides which, although I can't find the relevant JLawler post now, I think he did actually address the specific issue of whether rules of syntax, logic and/or precedent gave any definitive answer as to what the form should be, and said it was equally "unknowable" from that perspective as well as from what you think you hear.

@FumbleFingers - I do take your point about native speakers thinking they speak a certain way, when others might not think so. When I, aware of this issue, want to say 'used to', I deliberately enunciate the final 'd' of 'used' and make a tiny pause (like 'I used two packets of Dream Topping'). I dare any oscilloscope (even my double-beam Cossor Model 1049 from 1958 that weighs about 20 kg) to call me a liar.

but whether or not there's an intended and/or detected /d/ in 'I used two packets of Dream Topping') is irrelevant, since everyone can clearly distinguish the two different words in 'I use[d] to use two packets of Dream Topping') purely by whether the preceding consonant is /z/ or /s/. (But your oscilloscope sounds like one of "the heavy mob", so perhaps I'd better pipe down! :)

@FumbleFingers - I've realised that I say  'I uzed to like Morrissey, but not any more'  and 'I uzed two packets of Dream Topping', and 'I'm not uzed to being among violinists'. The 'scope is mainly decorative these days. Am I some sort of deviant?

haha - I'd say you are a deviant! Personally, I always pronounce have to / has to / had to as haFFta / haSSta / haTTta when they mean must, so from my perspective those are completely different words to to have as an auxiliary, or to convey "possession" (as JLawler also yoossta say). But I've reluctantly accepted that some people don't change the pronunciation, so they probably don't think the "must" versions are different words anyway. But I wasn't aware any native Anglophones don't distinguish I used to snore from I used pills to get to sleep.

@FumbleFingers - I'd never really thought about it before today. I normally speak a kind of RP/Lancs/South Derbyshire mixture so maybe it's from one of those.

I still remember how fascinated I was by that prince / prints issue maybe 20 years ago. I believe that until some time in the Middle Ages nobody could actually "read" without moving their lips, if not actually [sub]vocalizing the text. But even though my real-world ears aren't involved when I read (and I don't move my lips! :) I have the distinct impression my "inner voice" clearly distinguishes those two words!
